# Stop caching in jquery mobile with cordova on history back()

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

Our team made an app using cordova and jquery mobile. We kept every single page in different html files. Program navigates using window.location. But we have a small problem. App has a calendar where user can choose to add an event and directed to a form page. On this page user fill a form and post the new event to database and redirected to calendar page with historyback() function. But because the page is cached new event doesn't appear until you navigate there from a different page. How can we solve this problem? What is the best way to manage navigation in jquery mobile.

Comment: page caching is fine, why you don't reload the calendar data by using ajax?

Comment: @deblocker how can I trigger a reload? On.document(ready) won't work I guess.

Comment: see this great post of [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar) here: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) - you will find multi-page model, cached as well. Reload **data**  in `pagecontainerbeforeshow`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using historyback() for going back, use the page navigation feature of jquery mobile.The same way which you are using for going from page 1 to page 2. U can use the same to come back from page 2 to page 1.

syntax:-
jQuery.mobile.changePage( to [, options ] )

Ex:-
$.mobile.changePage( "#pageId", { transition: "slideup" });

Comment: And what happens when the user press the phone's back button? It will go back to form page

Comment: Check the active page when user clicks the back button and write a condition there. Find the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check the active page when user clicks the back button and write a condition there.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#login_page')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
       $.mobile.changePage( "#pageId", { transition: "slideup" });
    }
}, false);
```